# Change details of the tag inside the tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, tags

I hope that I can explain my question clearly.

```
<button type="button" class="" id="myId">
<p style="color: red;">hello</p>
</button>
```

How to change the attribute `style` of the tag `<p style="color: red;">hello</p>` if I only know that this tag is in the `<button>` tag with id `"myId"` using `jquery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('button#myId').find('p').css('color','red')
```

**OR**

```
$('button#myId').children().css('color','red')
```

If you have more than one element inside the button then you have to specific when you use children().

- [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)